# Fried egg safety

Tags: food-safety, eggs

I was cooking fried eggs today. 3.5 minutes on medium heat for both sides, the eggs were solid and yolk had been broken in with the whites, everything appeared solid outside. We noticed while eating that the majority of the egg was grandular like a hard-boiled egg, there was a pocket of yolk that was solid but more creamy and shiny. I cook for my elderly mil with cancer and try to be very careful about food safety. She shouldn't have undercooked eggs. Was this egg concerned undercooked? I have been looking at different cooking styles of eggs and believe the section looks like the right very yellow side of the attached egg picture. The paperwork the doctor gave us says we should be concerned with listeria and salmonella. Any advice is appreciated.[image]

Comment: Flagging to close this question since it's essentially request for medical advice.

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally consider that egg overcooked and give to the dog!

I ensure my eggs have as liquidy a yolk as possible, with only the whites solid - known as "over easy". Many restaurants and cooking shows cook them over-easy, so I'm sure you're safe.

Likewise seven minutes cooking an egg sounds absurdly on the high end. I cook mine for about a minute on each side (but only put it in the pan after the pan has already heated up medium hot).

What you described doesn't sound anywhere near undercooked.
Don't take that as medical advise, though!

Comment: Fried food for dogs is quite a bad idea.

Comment: @Mołot an egg shouldnt contain a lot of oil to cook it, so its ok to feed it with that, but another really fried foods *might not* be suitable to feed them, but doesnt really mean that you cant.

Comment: @Mołot Why's that? I mean, I give my dogs raw eggs. What's the difference between feeding them raw eggs and feeding them cooked eggs? (Note: my eggs are cooked using animal fat, usually chicken fat or pork lard)

Answer (score 1):

No this egg doesn't look undercooked. It may even bored on over cooked. Your MIL should be fine consuming it. As for the granular bits you described that could be a number of things (burnt bits of egg, coarse salt, etc.) it's hard to say.

Either way, nothing should be awry and she should be fine. If you want to give her better looking eggs, try sous vide it will give a better presentation and also be well cooked.